# Can I restrict a Content Editor Web Part to appear only for Contribute users?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Environment: SharePoint 2013.

I want a Content Editor webpart to appear only for the users who has contribute rights to a site/list.

I dont want to use Target Audience and key-in each SP groups, because the user rights are keep changing and new sharepoint groups are getting 'Contribute' rights.

Is there any simple way ? Is this possible using OOB ?

Answer (score 1):

You can place the CEWP inside `<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>`. Use appropriate permissions for `PermissionsString` property. An example:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="EditListItems">
  <div>
    CEWP Here
</div>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```